# How to Restrict a user account to single session via VPN to Windows 2008 R2 server?

Tags: login, windows-server-2008, vpn

I setup a VPN server and going to create an account for each user , but i don't want a user sign-in to the server from more than one place at time. I see some VPN Hosting in web offer VPN account and prevent multiple log-in for single user, but I couldn't find any solution for it.
How can we do it too?

Answer (score 0):

I search very in Google but couldn't find anything about it but I found a trick myself

**Restricting Multi-Login in Windows 2008 Server**

The following procedure is the simplest way that I found, just with one exception that just one random user can connect twice. he/she even could not connect more than twice and other user restricted to one connection too.

1. Set Static Root for 2 Range of IP in RRAS IP4 property page (Such as 192.168.100.1 - 192.168.100.2)
2. for each user in windows user property page > Dial-in page> Assign an static IP. (Such as 192.168.100.3)

Whats your idea about this trick?